# iOS5 app running on XCode w/ iOS6 freezes if the app after it goes to the background

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Hi I have an app that is working fine on iOS5, now running the app using iOS6 it freezes after it goes to the background and it goes back to the foreground, it no longer responds to touch events.

If I built it for 5.1 simulator works perfect, this only happend while running on iPhone 6.0 Simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mario, when you say freeze, I take it you mean when you bring it back to the foreground it no longer responds to touch events. Please elaborate

Comment: Yes, after it goes back to the foreground it no longer responds to touch events. 

Thanks, it is edited now.

Comment: Didn't it output any log or warning on Xcode when 'freezing'??

Comment: No, nothing, I have logs on all the delegate methods and it seems like it is only triggering this:  

- applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground

It is not entering here:  

applicationDidBecomeActive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT WITH ANSWER:

It turns out the culprit was the TWTweetComposeViewController, which I use in my application. 
I initialized TWTweetComposeViewController in my viewDidLoad function.  Apparently, if you initialize but do not show the TWTweetComposeViewController, it will prevent your application from resuming.  Check to see if you use this view controller and try removing it or not initializing it until you are going to show it.

Mario, I am having a similar, if not the same, problem.  In my case, my app hits applicationWillEnterForeground correctly as it resumes from the background.  However, the app seems to hang at this point and never reaches applicationDidBecomeActive.  I am at a loss for why the app would never reach applicationDidBecomeActive.  Like you, the app runs fine on iOS5 and below, but has this problem with iOS6.

Can you confirm that your app reaches applicationWillEnterForeground and doesn't hit applicationDidBecomeActive?

(I would write this as a comment to your question but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Please have some reputation then you can comment! Because you need 50 rep to leave comments on StackOverflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/why-cant-i-comment-on-this-answer